# How do those java sand games keep track of so many particles?

Tags: java, particles

Can anyone shed any light on how a program like that might be structured?

What java classes would they employ to keep track of so many particles and then check against them for things like collision detection? Particles need to know what particles they are next to, or that they're not next to anything so they can fall etc.

[Here's](http://fallingsandgame.com/sand/) an example, incase you're not sure what a sand game is.

Comment: Did you check out this thread?  http://www.scirra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6909&p=54531

Comment: The site you link to has a development forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays, mainly.

- A one-dimensional array of actively moving grains, represented by two coordinates (and possible a velocity if you want gravitational acceleration).
- A two-dimensional array of bools (or colours), representing the fixed parts of the world.

The simplest physics model is to remove a grain once it is at rest (e.g. when the world positions below, below to the left and below to the right are filled): instead, the corresponding world coordinate is filled in. This keeps the calculations manageable. Allow a grain to shift down if either the left or right below world coordinate is free. Grain collisions between moving grains can be ignored without loss of much verisimilitude.

(I can't quite get over how much CPU power we've got to spare these days!)

Comment: Verisimilitude is possibly the best word in existence. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Pontus I myself did an experiment with making a sand game in the HTML5 canvas. I looked this question up because I wanted to know if there's a more efficient way to do it, because the implementation I made is slower than hell. The weird thing is, javascript is powerful enough that it can track 1200+ objects in a 3D environment with zero lag, but 200 objects in an experimental falling sand app will bring it to its knees. [Here](http://codesocialist.com/#/?s=b4) is my experiment. You'll notice I have an array for every particle, and an array for "ground" particles.

Answer (score 1):

The simple version can be implemented without much trouble on a loose friday night (like I did just now). Simply make a program with a 2D array (of bytes, ints, whatever) representing your field. In each tick, iterate over all the elements and do a check:

- If the field below (array[x][y+1]) is empty, move 1 spot down (= set [x][y] to empty, [x][y+1] to occupied)
- Else, if [x-1][y+1] is empty, go there.
- Else, if [x+1][y+1] is empty, go there.

That's the basics. Next you have to add checks like not 'repeating' the calculation for a grain (set a flag at the new position that's checked at the following iterations).

I followed [this](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/09/29/falling-sand-style-water-simulation/) tutorial, it's quite good, not too long but still points out common pitfalls and things like that.

Comment: You could avoid repeating checks by iterating through the 2D array from the bottom up, right?

Comment: @KartikChugh Yes, unless you also have a material that goes bottom-up, like a gas or smoke particle.