# Particle pile algorithm

Tags: java, android, game-physics

I'm creating a game which has around 3000 particles that fall into a pile.  The particles are each a pixel and i just use a boolean[][] to set and check which pixel is clear.  Right now i am using this code

```
if (!isFalling(m)) {
    if (isClear(getX() + 1, getY()) && isClear(getX() + 1, getY() - 1))
        setX(getX() + 1);
    else if (isClear(getX() - 1, getY()) && isClear(getX() - 1, getY() - 1)
        setX(getX() - 1);
}
```

the problem is that this code gives me a very strict pyramid shape which doesnt look very natural.  I want it to look something like salt would if you poured it into a pile.  My question is, does anyone know of an algorithm or a better way to simulate particle piles?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solution: 
I have found a nice article [here](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/09/29/falling-sand-style-water-simulation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've taken on a big task :)  It's not just how to calculate and draw the particles, it's the physics which describe how they should move.

Take a look at this for a starter:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/426676/sand-game-problem-with-graphics

When Googling, try "particle generator" or "particle emitter".

Also see this question:

[How do those java sand games keep track of so many particles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460849/how-do-those-java-sand-games-keep-track-of-so-many-particles)

The main thing you might be missing is to add randomness, some entropy, into your system.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Both of those methods are very similar to what i am currently doing but ill try to incorporate some into my code.  Ill keep looking and see what i can come up with

Answer (score 2):

So your function looks at particles which have settled to the bottom and asks if they can slide down the side, and then effects that motion if they can.

Do you have this in a loop? If so, you may be considering particles from the "bottom up" whereas the sliding motion may take place at any point on the pile. You could try shuffling the particle list prior to performing the loop, or repeatedly choosing random elements from the list until you get a low rate of settling.

In the case of a 2D array, you could try looping from different directions or finding other ways of mixing it up - again choosing pixels at random may not be a bad choice. Simulated annealing comes to mind.

Or, you could add a random check to your sliding condition. The particles should be semi-stable in their initial positions, so maybe there's only a 50% chance of them sliding down the side.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have this in a game loop so it checks the position every frame and moves only one position a frame.  You talk about starting in different positions but the way i have it set up is i have an object with the position of each particle and to avoid checking against on another, i use a 2d array to map the positions. this cuts down on the checks tremendously.  So each object is updated and then mapped and then rendered based on the pos coords in the object.

Comment: Checks all the positions every frame? The loop I refer to is the one which checks the particle's positions.

Comment: No it updates half one frame then updates the other the next. on the android i can render about 4000 at greater than 40 fps.  Not bad.  obvoiusly it could be split even more to improve performance but that can be dealt with later.  As of right now i am just trying to determine mechanics.  So you are saying that i should loop through each particle in a different order each time?

Comment: about the checking from the bottom. i have tried that and it looks more "natural" however it gives me an upside down looking parabola.  What i was doing was checking if there were 2 particles above the current and moving left or right accordingly